# git different folder casing in branches and ls-remote

Tags: git

something is wrong in my git repository. I get different case for the branch folder name. `git branch -r` gives me *US/blabla* `git ls-remote` gives me *us/blabla* thats true for all the remote us/

why is this happening, how can I make both command return the lowercase version?

**command:**

```
git branch -r | grep US/blabla
```

**returns:**

```
origin/US/99867_blabla
```

**command:**

```
git ls-remote origin US/99867_blabla
```

**returns** `nothing`

**command:**

```
git ls-remote origin us/99867_blabla
```

**returns**

```
`12312362b8f4e6dc0e1c34880f96d525d2d19d30        refs/heads/us/blabla`
```

**command:**

```
git branch
```

**returns**

```
* master
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Git itself* thinks that all uppercase letters are always distinct from all lowercase letters.  Hence a file or branch named `NAME` is always different from one named `name`.  A file named `INCLUDE/IP.H` is different from one named `include/ip.h`.  Note that these two names have a slash in them.  There is no *folder* named `INCLUDE` or `include` here, there are just *files* named `INCLUDE/IP.H` and `include/ip.h`.  The same holds for branch names: `FEATURE/NAME` and `feature/name` do not have any folders; they're just two different branch names.

At various times, however, Git is forced, by your computer, to place these file or branch names into your computer's file and/or folder names.<sup>1</sup>  If the file system provided by your computer requires that slashes imply folders, Git will create a folder for you at this time, so as to hold the full name.  If the file system provided by your computer conflates uppercase and lowercase, so that `NAME` and `name` are considered "the same file" and `INCLUDE` and `include` are "the same folder", the various files and folders that Git is trying to create and use here will get mixed together.

**What Git does with these problematic cases is to make you, the user, miserable.**  The people who write and support Git code have put in various attempts to make the experience less horrible, but none of them have really solved the problem, because there is no single satisfactory solution.  **Your best bet is to avoid this situation entirely, if you can.**  If not, you must live with the weirdness until you manage to rename everything to get *out* of this bad situation.

Make sure that you are consistent in when or whether you use uppercase or lowercase.  One relatively easy way to deal with all of this is to obtain a Linux system (or a Linux VM with a private file system), or create a case-sensitive file system on your computer, so that when Git goes to create a folder or file named `NAME` and another *different* folder or file named `name`, it winds up with two different folders / files.  Using Git on *this* system will work fine and will give you the opportunity to get rid of files and/or branches that use the "wrong" case.

Remember that in Git, history *is* commits.  Commits *contain* files (never any folders, just files, even if their names have slashes in them) and those files have names, and uppercase letters are always different from lowercase ones here.  Old commits *cannot be changed* so if you have files that differ only in case in these old commits, they will continue to be that way in the old commits.  Just make *new* commits in which the problem no longer exists, and avoid using the old commits on computers / file-systems where they are a problem.  If necessary, you can even "rewrite history" by copying the old problematic commits to new-and-improved ones that avoid the problem, then making your branch and tag and other names remember *only* the new commits.  Remember that any Git repository that has the *old* commits will re-introduce them to your fixed-up Git repository, so if you *do* rewrite history, everyone with a clone of the bad history must get rid of the bad history somehow—typically by abandoning the old clone entirely.

Fortunately, in your case, the issue is just *branch names*.  Unfortunately, branch names *also* get copied by cloning.  Fortunately, they're merely copied to *remote-tracking names*.  So once you've fixed up the original source of the misery, you can, on each clone, just *delete all remote-tracking names* and then *re-obtain them all*, perhaps using:

```
git remote remove origin
```

followed by:

```
git remote add origin <url>
git fetch origin
```

with the appropriate URL (you can save it before doing the `git remote remove` operation).

---

<sup>1</sup>Since Git *is* eventually going to put information about a branch named `feature/name` into a folder named `feature` containing a file named `name`, Git won't let you create a *branch* named `feature` if you have a *branch* named `feature/name`.  That accommodates the fact that even on a Linux system with case-sensitive file names, Git *can't* create both a *file* named `feature` *and* a file named `feature/name`.  If Git always stored all branch information in *encoded* names, rather than just using the branch's name as a path-name, this particular problem would go away—as would the case-folding issues.  In my opinion, this is the right way to solve all the branch case-folding problems.  It does nothing for any *file name* case-folding problems, though.

Answer (score 0):

`origin/US/99867_blabla` is a remote-tracking branch that exists in the *local* repository, and `refs/heads/us/blabla` returned by `git ls-remote` is a branch that exists in the *remote* repository.

From the output of the 3 commands, we can guess that `US/99867_blabla` does not exist in the remote repository any longer. It may have been renamed or deleted. If so, the local `origin/US/99867_blabla` is negligible and useless.

Try `git fetch --prune`, which is expected to create `origin/us/blabla` and delete `origin/US/99867_blabla`.

Comment: all the branches under us/ are treated as US/ ... git fetch --prune does not help

branches with US never existed.

Comment: Does `origin/us/blabla` exist in `git branch -r`?

Comment: nope only at ls-remote
also I see that .git\refs\remotes\origin\US exists.
changing it to .git\refs\remotes\origin\us solves the problem.
and the problem doesn't happen in a new clone.
but what caused it in the first place? got this on like 10 machines

Comment: It's not a good idea to change the folder names under `.git/refs`.  If `origin/US/*` are all packed, by `git gc` for example, `.git/refs/remotes/origin/US` does not exist.